# Store react native callback function

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I have a problem with react native android module, Is there any way to store callback functions in shared preferences? Idea is that to store call back functions in shared preferences to call them after app destroyed.

I have made a module to launch in background, It will start service after app destroyed, it is working, but after application destroyed, call back functions are removing from stack, I'm trying to find a way to store that functions and call them after app destroyed.

Please Help, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try React Native Event Listeners as callback function
[React Native Event Listeners](https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners)

https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners

Comment: But how should I use that to preventing from removing listener from stack?

Comment: Why are you use  shared preferences? Are you use native code in react-native project. If maintain only react-native then you will use 'Headless JS'  for module to launch in background and it works after app destroy.

Comment: And If use native code(Android) in react-native then add view bridge (React Native Bridge for Android and iOS) onDestroy method in MainActivity.java
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Constants.debugLog(TAG, "onDestroy()  ");
    }